# Set accessor not being called when I deserialise object from Json.net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, accessor

```
public class SpecialObject
{
    public string ID;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<SpecialObject> SpecialObjectCollection = new List<SpecialObject>();
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<string> tempObjectIDs = new List<string>();

    [JsonProperty]
    public List<string> SpecialObjectIDs { get { return SpecialObjectCollection.Select(x => x.ID).ToList(); } set { tempObjectIDs = value; } }

    public SpecialObject() { }
    public SpecialObject(string _id) { ID = _id; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SpecialObject parent = new SpecialObject("parentIDstring");
    parent.SpecialObjectCollection.Add(new SpecialObject("childIDstring"));

    string test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent);
    SpecialObject reconstructedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpecialObject>(test);
}

//string test:
//{"ID":"parentIDstring","SpecialObjectIDs":["childIDstring"]}
```

I want to serialise SpecialObject to JSON and back again. The "SpecialObjectIDs" accessor lets me avoid nasty circular references and helps me reconstruct the complex relational network since I only need the unique IDs.

It serialises just fine, but I need to deserialise the objects; when I do so, my array (SpecialObjectIDs in JSON) just disappears during the conversion, the set accessor doesnt seem to be called.

How do I get the Newtonsoft.Json (JSON.net) library to put the deserialised List in tempObjectIDs but keep the existing get behavior?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. It doesn't look like it would even compile at the moment, due to `SpecialObject.Select`. It doesn't help that we don't know what the JSON looks like, either.

Comment: Sorry I pulled it out of a larger project. Fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that, when deserializing a collection that is not read-only, Json.NET checks to see if the collection has already been allocated, for instance in the constructor of the containing type.  If so, it fills the pre-existing collection for the deserialized JSON contents, and never sets the collection back.  Unfortunately, your property returns a temporary proxy collection, so your container class `SpecialObject` never receives the deserialized results.

The simplest way to prevent this is to specify that Json.NET should always allocate a new collection and set it back rather than reuse the pre-existing collection, via the [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ObjectCreationHandling.htm) setting [`ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ObjectCreationHandling.htm)

```
[JsonProperty(ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)]
public List<string> SpecialObjectIDs { get { return SpecialObjectCollection.Select(x => x.ID).ToList(); } set { tempObjectIDs = value; } }
```

Alternatively you could use a `string []` rather than a `List<string>` for your proxy collection property:

```
public string [] SpecialObjectIDs { get { return SpecialObjectCollection.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray(); } set { tempObjectIDs = value == null ? null : value.ToList(); } }
```

As arrays cannot be resized, Json.NET will always allocate a new array when deserializing and set it back when complete.

Comment: Thank you that worked! That seems like an obscure issue, when I was fiddling around earlier I managed to trigger an error that hinted at "tempObjectIDs" already existing, I'm surprised it didn't just throw an exception in my sample code.